# Fetch a set of words(char and non char seperated by space) from a sentence appearing prior to a particular words in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I want to split a sentence and fetch a subset of words seperated by space , prior to a specific word in Oracle SqL.

I tried regexp substring, instring but couldn't  arrive at solution.

**Source sentences:**
Being 25 % commission on package item charged

Being 27.5 % Withholding tax on items debited

Being 30.09876 % survey fees on services delivered.

**Condition**:
Fetch all words prior to the first appearance of word 'on'

**Expected output:**
Being 25 % commission

Being 27.5 % withholding tax

Being 30.09876 % survey fees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `^(.*?[^[:alpha:]])??(on[^[:alpha:]].*)?$` and, if matched, replace the value with the contents of the first capturing group:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         value,
         '^(.*?[^[:alpha:]])??(on[^[:alpha:]].*)?$',
         '\1',
         1,
         1,
         'i'
       ) AS value_until_first_on
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT 'Being 25 % commission on package item charged' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Being 27.5 % Withholding tax on items debited' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Being 30.09876 % survey fees on services delivered.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alice has a hat with flowers on, it is pretty.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'On Tuesday, it was hot.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'This sentence ends with on' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'One Two Three Four' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Four Three Two One Zero' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'We went, on Tuesday, on the train.' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE                                               | VALUE_UNTIL_FIRST_ON         
> :-------------------------------------------------- | :----------------------------
> Being 25 % commission on package item charged       | Being 25 % commission        
> Being 27.5 % Withholding tax on items debited       | Being 27.5 % Withholding tax 
> Being 30.09876 % survey fees on services delivered. | Being 30.09876 % survey fees 
> Alice has a hat with flowers on, it is pretty.      | Alice has a hat with flowers 
> On Tuesday, it was hot.                             | null                         
> This sentence ends with on                          | This sentence ends with on   
> One Two Three Four                                  | One Two Three Four           
> Four Three Two One Zero                             | Four Three Two One Zero      
> We went, on Tuesday, on the train.                  | We went,
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ebcb33179a56532b93e00cb87ac61033)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple SUBSTR and REGEXP_INSTR

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    sentences (sentence)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Being 25 % commission on package item charged' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Being 27.5 % Withholding tax on items debited' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Being 30.09876 % survey fees on services delivered' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Alice has a hat with flowers on, it is pretty.' FROM DUAL)
SELECT sentence,
       SUBSTR (sentence, 1, REGEXP_INSTR (sentence, '\Won\W') - 1)     AS short_sentence
  FROM sentences;
```

#### Result

```
                                             SENTENCE                  SHORT_SENTENCE
_____________________________________________________ _______________________________
Being 25 % commission on package item charged         Being 25 % commission
Being 27.5 % Withholding tax on items debited         Being 27.5 % Withholding tax
Being 30.09876 % survey fees on services delivered    Being 30.09876 % survey fees
Alice has a hat with flowers on, it is pretty.        Alice has a hat with flowers
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the sentence `'Alice has a hat with flowers on, it is pretty.'`

Comment: Just updated it to use REGEXP_INSTR instead of INSTR